# What does the red rectangle mean in vs code？

Tags: visual-studio-code

I searched the similar questions, not found the answer. I guess I pressed a hot key, but I do not remember which one is...

[image]

Emmm...

After restart VS Code, it's become normal.

(Still do not know why...)

Comment: it's like an extension

Comment: use **Extension Bisect** (Extension bar top menu) to determine which extension is causing this

Comment: does the color change if you change the Theme

Comment: Thanks, guys.  I can not trigger it again, the next time I will try Theme or Extension Bisect.